# How to show sliding windows of a numpy array with matplotlib FuncAnimation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I am developing a simple algorithm for the detection of peaks in a signal. To troubleshoot my algorithm (and to showcase it), I would like to observe the signal and the detected peaks all along the signal duration (i.e. `20` minutes at `100Hz` = `20000` time-points).

I thought that the best way to do it would be to create an animated plot with `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` that would continuously show the signal sliding by 1 time-points and its superimposed peaks within a time windows of `5` seconds (i.e. `500` time-points). The signal is stored in a 1D `numpy.ndarray` while the peaks information are stored in a 2D `numpy.ndarray` containing the `x` and `y` coordinates of the peaks.

This is a "still frame" of how the plot would look like.

[image]

Now the problem is that I cannot wrap my head around the way of doing this with FuncAnimation.

If my understanding is correct I need three main pieces: the `init_func` parameter, a function that create the empty frame upon which the plot is drawn, the `func` parameter, that is the function that actually create the plot for each frame, and the parameter `frames` which is defined in the help as `Source of data to pass func and each frame of the animation`.

Looking at examples of plots with `FuncAnimation`, I can only find use-cases in which the data to plot are create on the go, like [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), or [here](https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/23558/basic-animation-with-funcanimation), where the data to plot are **created** on the basis of the `frame`.

What I do not understand is how to implement this with data that are already there, but that are **sliced** on the basis of the frame.  I would thus need the `frame` to work as a sort of sliding window, in which the first window goes from `0` to `499`, the second from `1`to `500` and so on until the end of the time-points in the `ndarray`, and an associated `func` that will select the points to plot on the basis of those `frames`. I do not know how to implement this.

I add the code to create a realistic signal, to simply detect the peaks and to plot the 'static' version of the plot I would like to animate:

```
import neurokit2 as nk
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
#create realistic data
data = nk.ecg_simulate(duration = 50, sampling_rate = 100, noise = 0.05,\
                       random_state = 1)
#scale data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_arr = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1,1))
#find peaks
peak = find_peaks(scaled_arr.squeeze(), height = .66,\
        distance = 60, prominence = .5)
#plot
plt.plot(scaled_arr[0:500])
plt.scatter(peak[0][peak[0] < 500],\
         peak[1]['peak_heights'][peak[0] < 500],\
             color = 'red')
```

Comment: If you want answers, you are expected to provide reproducible data. Respondents have the hassle of creating their own sample data and the psychological burden of new revisions that may occur because the data they create is different from your data. It is even better if you have the code in the process of creation.

Comment: You are completely right. I have added the code to create data, detect peaks and create the static version of the plot that I would like to animate. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an animation using the data you presented; I've extracted the data in 500 increments for 5000 data and updated the graph. To make it easy to extract the data, I have created an index of 500 rows, where id[0] is the start row, id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofeJx.gif) is the end row, and the number of frames is 10. This code works, but the initial settings and dataset did not work in the scatter plot, so I have drawn the scatter plot directly in the loop process.

```
import neurokit2 as nk
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np

#create realistic data
data = nk.ecg_simulate(duration = 50, sampling_rate = 100, noise = 0.05, random_state = 1)

#scale data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_arr = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1,1))
#find peaks
peak = find_peaks(scaled_arr.squeeze(), height = .66, distance = 60, prominence = .5)

ymin, ymax = min(scaled_arr), max(scaled_arr)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([],[], lw=2)
scat = ax.scatter([], [], s=20, facecolor='red')

idx = [(s,e) for s,e in zip(np.arange(0,len(scaled_arr), 1), np.arange(499,len(scaled_arr)+1, 1))]

def init():
    line.set_data([], []) 
    return line, 

def animate(i):
  id = idx[i]
  #print(id[0], id[1])
  line.set_data(np.arange(id[0], id[1]), scaled_arr[id[0]:id[1]])
  x = peak[0][(peak[0] > id[0]) & (peak[0] < id[1])]
  y = peak[1]['peak_heights'][(peak[0] > id[0]) & (peak[0] < id[1])]
  #scat.set_offsets(x, y)
  ax.scatter(x, y, s=20, c='red')
  ax.set_xlim(id[0], id[1])
  ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
  return line,scat

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=50, interval=50, blit=True) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have time to deal with the assignment anymore, but maybe tomorrow I'll have time.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely goes in the right direction and gives me some good idea. I will try to mange to make it work to show the signal at 1 time-point increase within a 5 seconds windows.

Comment: What aspects of my response do not meet your requirements?

Comment: Your solution plots non-overlapping windows of `5` seconds. It is possible that it was not clear from my question, but I would like the signal to be plotted a time-point at a time, _within_ a `5` seconds window. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Are you talking about adding to the 5 second unit from the beginning? I didn't understand the question that way. Do you want me to modify the code? Or can you handle it yourself?

Comment: I was thinking to something like the medical devices that show the ECG signal. You turn it on, the display is empty, you plug the ECG, the signal start to be drawn, when the display window is full (this would be my `5` seconds window) the older signal goes out of the frame on the right and the new signal is plotted on the left. Does this explain it ?

Comment: I finally understood what it meant. It's like an oscilloscope. Updated the code and animations; due to the 2MB limit, the number of frames is set to 50, but please change it to draw all the data.

Comment: That's exactly it and I am accepting the answer. Just one thing that maybe you can help me clarify: if I copy paste your code, both axes in the plot are set between +.4 and -.4, and the peaks do not get plotted. However, if I set `blit = False`, then the axes are well scaled, the peaks get plotted, but of course the advancement is much slower, since all the plot get constantly recreated. Any idea about why this could be ?

Comment: blit=True is a parameter to speed up drawing. By enabling it, the previous drawing is not drawn. See here for more [information](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html). Also, `set_ylim(ymin,ymax)` is specified without the animation function, so you can see in the attached GIF that there is no break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238697/discussion-between-fednem-and-r-beginners).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not exactly what you want, but hope it can help,

```
import neurokit2 as nk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):

    xs = xs[i]
    ys = ys[i]

    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

if __name__=="__main__":
   
  data = nk.ecg_simulate(duration = 50, sampling_rate = 100, noise = 0.05, random_state = 1)
  scaler = MinMaxScaler()
  scaled_arr = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1,1))
  
  ys = scaled_arr.flatten()
  ys = [ys[0:50*i] for i in range(1, int(len(ys)/50)+1)]
  xs = [np.arange(0, len(ii)) for ii in ys ]
  
 
  ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=500)
  ani.save('test.gif')
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good and it definitely points me in the right direction, I just need to find a way to avoid the "cumulative effect" and make it stick the plot to a 5 seconds window.